# python one-liner to do arithmetic operation on one element with same index for all sublists

Tags: python, list

For example: I need to create a `list2` as `[[2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0]]` from existing list `[[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0]]`. The index of the element is the same among all the sublist (0). How to achieve using one-liner?

I have tried:

```
list=[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]
list2=[i[0]+1 for i in list]  # only ends up with [2,3,4]
[i[0]=i[0]+1 for i in list]   # invalid syntax
```

Comment: It is usually wise to not name your list *list*, since it over shadows the built-in class *list*.

Comment: what if the size of the sublist is not the same?

Comment: see my edited solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list2 = [[i+1,j], for [i,j] in list]`

if your sublists have different lengths:

`list2 = [[x[0]+1]+x[1:] for x in list]`

Answer (score 1):

`[[x[0]+1,x[1]] for x in list]`
although you really should not name things list because of name conflicts